# Why does using yield inside __next__() return generators?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, iterable

The python documentation states:

> iterator.__next__()
>
> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception.

So according to that, if I have a class that I want to make iterable, where the iteration should happen over a given already iterable field of that class, I should be able to use `yield` in a loop over said field and return `StopIteration` after the loop.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__l = list(range(10))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        for x in self.__l:
            yield x # return next item from container
        raise StopIteration # if there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception.
```

But this gets me an infiinte loop of generators:

```
c = C()
for x in c:
    print(x)
```

output:

```
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6afc0>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6a678>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6afc0>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6a678>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6afc0>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6a678>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6afc0>
<generator object C.__next__ at 0x10fa6a678>
...
```

Why is that? Where am I misinterpreting the documentation?

I could just have done

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.__l)
```

and not implement `__next__()` but that is not the point of my question.

## edit:

Yes, I had already read that supposed duplicate. It does specifically not answer my question.

Comment: **Every** function that contains a `yield` statement returns a generator. That's the whole purpose of `yield`. You can't use it to implement a `__next__` method. (You *could* use it to implement an `__iter__` method though.)

Comment: I agree that the answer in the dupe doesn't do a good job of explaining anything, but I'm reluctant to reopen because the questions *are* exactly identical. We don't want to have answers to the same question in two different places; people should post their answers on the dupe instead.

Comment: Why would anybody post an answer to a 2 year old question, that already has an accepted answer (even though that answer does not actually answer the question).

Comment: Because your question has brought attention to the fact that no proper answer exists yet. If nobody posts an answer in the next hour I'll post one myself.